# Pivot in SQL without Aggregate function

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a scenario Where I have a table like

Table View

[image]

and What Output I want is

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @D.Jay . . . I don't understand the question.  Do you want to re-format the data?  Or do you want to specify how SQL engines work?

Comment: @Gordon Here i want to re-format the data.

Answer (score 1):

If your argument is "I will only ever have one value or no values, therefore I don't want an aggregate", realise that there are several aggregates that, if they're only passed a single value to aggregate, will return that value back as their result. `MIN` and `MAX` come to mind. `SUM` also works for numeric data.

Therefore the solution to specifying a `PIVOT` without an aggregate is instead to specify such a "pass through" aggregate here.

Basically, `PIVOT` internally works a lot the same as `GROUP BY`. Except the grouping columns are all columns in the current result set *other than* the column mentioned in the aggregate part of the `PIVOT` specification. And just as with the rules for the `SELECT` clause when `GROUP BY` is used<sup>1</sup>, every column *either* needs to be a grouping column or contained in an aggregate.

---

<sup>1</sup>Grumble, grumble, older [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) grumble. Although the defaults are more sensible from 5.7.5 up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbc38a7821b24e01735f8df346114bdb)

```
with cte1 as
(
select 'Web' as platformname,'abc' as productname,'A' as grade
union all
select 'Web' ,'cde' ,'B'
union all
select 'IOS' ,'xyz' ,'C'
union all
select 'MAX' ,'cde' ,'D'
)
select  productname,[Web], [IOS], [Android],[Universal],[Mac],[Win32]
from    cte1 t
        pivot
        (
            max(grade)
            for platformname in ([Web], [IOS], [Android],[Universal],[Mac],[Win32])
        ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "pivot" such data using `join`s:

```
select p.productname,
       t_win32.grade as win32,
       t_universal.grade as universal,
       . . .
from products p left join -- assume you have such a table
     t t_win32
     on t_win32.product_name = p.productname and t_win32.platform = 'Win32' left join
     t t_universal
     on t_universal.product_name = p.productname and t_universal.platform = 'Universal'  left join
     . . .
```

If you don't have a table `products`, use a derived table instead:

```
from (select distinct product_name from t) p left join
     . . .
```

Comment: thanks. Here What is the scenario the very first image is my table structure and here one column is named "PlatformName". now in the output, I want to show this  rows values in the column and "SLTGrade" in rows as their corresponding values, the problem is I am not much familiar with SQL queries